# Accessing a variable from inside a do-while loop

Tags: java, variables, while-loop, scope, do-while

How can I access a variable from inside a do-while loop in Java?

The code below writes out a value until the value entered is not is between 0 and 10.

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoWhileRange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 an 10");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a = in.nextInt();
                int total +=0;
        }while (a>0 && a<10);

        System.out.println("Loop Terminated");
        System.out.println("The total is : "+total);
    }
}
```

The loop continues to ask for input so long as the input is between 0 and 10. Once some other number is entered the loop terminates and displays the total of all inputted numbers.

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  *Where* are you trying to access the variable?

Comment: Additional to the answers below, you probably mean `(a>=0 && a<=10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like (declare the variable a outside the loop):

```
    int a = -1;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 an 10");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = in.nextInt();
    }while (a>0 && a<10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but why are you intialiazing `int a = -1` and not `int a = 0` ?

Comment: it can be 0 also, but just to be on safer side, you are checking for > 0 but later may include 0 as well but chance of including negative number is much less

Comment: interesting concept ... for sure will keep mind ... it might save a few lines every now and then ... i never thought about it !

Comment: @vishal_aim - Hi. Please don't approve [suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2114868) without seeing changes.

Comment: You don't need to initialize it at all.

Answer (score 2):

To access a variable beyond the loop, you need to declare/initialize it outside of the loop and then change it inside the loop. If the variable in question wasn't an int, I would suggest that you initialize it to null. However, since you can't initialize an int variable to null, you'll have to initialize it to some random value:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoWhileRange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int a = 0; //create it here
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 an 10");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            a = in.nextInt();
        } while (a>0 && a<10);
        System.out.println("Loop Terminated");
        // do something with a
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you simply declare the variable before the loop without initializing it (as per @Evginy's answer), you'll be able to access it outside the loop but your compiler will complain that it might not have been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 an 10");
        a = in.nextInt();
    } while (a > 0 && a < 10);
    System.out.println("Loop Terminated");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do however want to keep the `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` inside the loop  no ? I don't really care for it outside the loop